# Deriving $PV^n = \text{constant}$ for polytropic processes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to understand a derivation of the formula $PV^n = \text{constant}$ as given to me by my uni teacher.

Knowing that heat capacity $C = dQ/dT \implies dQ = CdT$

and the first law of thermodynamics stated as $dQ = dU + dW = dU + pdV$

we get

$$ CdT = dU + pdV $$

I more or less understand until this point. But then, my notes go:

$$
CdT =
\left(\frac{dU}{dT}\right)_V dT
+ \left[ \left(\frac{dU}{dV}\right)_T + P \right] dV
$$

*(the subscripts indicate constant volume or temperature)*

I can’t wrap my head around this. Going back from the equation above I get

$$ cdT = dU + dU + pdV \neq dU + pdV $$

(symbolically simplifying by $dT$ and $dV$)

---

Actually this is not for me but somebody else I am helping. My understanding of thermodynamics is practically zero, so I can only help with the algebra given all the formulae and equations. It is also a little strange to me that we mix the concept derivatives such as $dU/dT$ (which, AFAIK is to be interpreted as the *limit* of this as $dT$ approaches $0$) and ‘simple’ fractions. I am sure these transformations can be justified somehow, though.

Does the answer have to do with $dU$ being an extremely small number and the fact that a difference of $dU$ is negligible? This seems wrong though, I get the feeling that here we are supposed to treat all $d$-values as any other variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of polytropic process equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/derivation-of-polytropic-process-equation)

Comment: The heat transferred is not dQ=CdT.  For an ideal gas, the change in internal energy is dU=CdT.

Comment: The formula you wrote can't be derived because it is the definition of a polytropic process.  Hheat is added and the temperature changes in such a way that this equation is always satisfied at all points along the process.

Comment: @FakeMod not really, although I should have chosen a better title for this question. It is not so much about the derivation than a certain step to acquire an equation as part of the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notes are misleading you. The $\mathrm dU$ here is an [exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential):
$$
\mathrm dU(T,\,V)=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\mathrm dT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\mathrm dV
$$
rather than the derivatives you have. Hence, you cannot cancel the $\mathrm dT$'s and $\mathrm dV$'s as you've done.

Comment: The confusion came from my lack of my lacking calculus knowledge and the fact that the notes wildly mix the symbols $\partial$ and $d$, for example $\frac{\partial U}{d V}$ and similar. Thanks, this solves the question asked.